# Limiting number of running tasks in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a situation where I would like to limit the number of concurrent running tasks. If you look into the code below..

```
public class TaskScheduler
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var taskProcessor = new TaskProcessor();

        // Run infinite loop
        while (true)
        {
            taskProcessor.Process();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class TaskProcessor
{
    private const int MaxConcurrentTasks = 4;

    public void Process()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < MaxConcurrentTasks; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWorkAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Situation**: Currently new Tasks are created every second regardless of previous tasks have been completed or not. The TaskScheduler.Initialize() function calls taskProcessor.Process() every second, forcing the TaskProcessor to Start new tasks.

**Desired Output:** What is required is, regardless of `TaskScheduler.Initialize()` makes a call to `taskProcessor.Process()` every second, `TaskProcessor.Process()` should only Start `MaxConcurrentTasks` (i.e 4 in this example) Tasks at one point.... For example, if 4 tasks are processing than not create any new tasks.... if 3 are Running but one is finished than only Start 1 new task and so on...

I would really appreciate if someone can provide me with a direction about how this can be efficiently achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating new threads each time rather than having the thread get the next item to work on?